# How to make server info discord.js cmd

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm making a discord bot and I want to add a server info command, when I run the command it gave me an error message "Command.execute is not an function","message create actio center","Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE]".

Here is my code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const moment = require('moment');

const filterLevels = {
    DISABLED: 'Off',
    MEMBERS_WITHOUT_ROLES: 'No Role',
    ALL_MEMBERS: 'Everyone'
};

const verificationLevels = {
    NONE: 'None',
    LOW: 'Low',
    MEDIUM: 'Medium',
    HIGH: '(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻',
    VERY_HIGH: '┻━┻ ﾐヽ(ಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻'
};

const regions = {
    brazil: 'Brazil',
    europe: 'Europe',
    hongkong: 'Hong Kong',
    india: 'India',
    japan: 'Japan',
    russia: 'Russia',
    singapore: 'Singapore',
    southafrica: 'South Africa',
    sydeny: 'Sydeny',
    'us-central': 'US Central',
    'us-east': 'US East',
    'us-west': 'US West',
    'us-south': 'US South'
};

module.exports = {
    name: 'server',
    aliases: [],
    description: 'server info...',
    cooldown: 5,
    guildOnly: false,
    args: false,
 run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.sort((a, b) => b.position - a.position).map(role => role.toString());
        const members = message.guild.members.cache;
        const channels = message.guild.channels.cache;
        const emojis = message.guild.emojis.cache;

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`**Server Info**`)
            .setColor('BLACK')
            .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .addField('General', [
                `**Name:** ${message.guild.name}`,
                `**ID:** ${message.guild.id}`,
                `**Owner:** ${message.guild.owner.user.tag} (${message.guild.ownerID})`,
                `**Region:** ${regions[message.guild.region]}`,
                `**Boost Tier:** ${message.guild.premiumTier ? `Tier ${message.guild.premiumTier}` : 'None'}`,
                `**Explicit Filter:** ${filterLevels[message.guild.explicitContentFilter]}`,
                `**Verification Level:** ${verificationLevels[message.guild.verificationLevel]}`,
                `**Time Created:** ${moment(message.guild.createdTimestamp).format('LT')} ${moment(message.guild.createdTimestamp).format('LL')} [${moment(message.guild.createdTimestamp).fromNow()}]`,
                '\u200b'
            ])
            .addField('Statistics', [
                `**Role Count:** ${roles.length}`,
                `**Emoji Count:** ${emojis.size}`,
                `**Regular Emoji Count:** ${emojis.filter(emoji => !emoji.animated).size}`,
                `**Animated Emoji Count:** ${emojis.filter(emoji => emoji.animated).size}`,
                `**Member Count:** ${message.guild.memberCount}`,
                `**Humans:** ${members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}`,
                `**Bots:** ${members.filter(member => member.user.bot).size}`,
                `**Text Channels:** ${channels.filter(channel => channel.type === 'text').size}`,
                `**Voice Channels:** ${channels.filter(channel => channel.type === 'voice').size}`,
                `**Boost Count:** ${message.guild.premiumSubscriptionCount || '0'}`,
                '\u200b'
            ])
            .addField('Presence', [
                `**Online:** ${members.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'online').size}`,
                `**Idle:** ${members.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'idle').size}`,
                `**Do Not Disturb:** ${members.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'dnd').size}`,
                `**Offline:** ${members.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'offline').size}`,
                '\u200b'
            ])
            .addField(`Roles [${roles.length - 1}]`, roles.join(', '))
    
            .setTimestamp();
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }

}
```

I don't really know how to fix it since I'm pretty new to JavaScript.

Comment: Since you're new to JavaScript; I'd not follow this example one bit. Too many things to understand!!!

Follow this, or something much more friendlier with an ECMAScript 5-6 type language going on. https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is in your command handle. In your command handler, you get the command, then you try to do `Command.execute(client, message, args)`. That would be fine, but in your command that you just shared, the function is called `run` not `execute`.

If it's called run in all of your commands, just change the command handle to be `Command.run(client, message args);`, but if its just the server info command just change the function's name from run to execute. Hope that helped.